# What is the table() equivalent of R for python?

Tags: python

Say you have a vector(or list, in python) of factors such as

```
siblings_number = [1, 2 ,3, 2, 1, 0, 0...]
```

which is a list of number of siblings for 50 students (who responded to a survey). 
In R, this would be really easy to tabulate and plot as a barchart. However, I can't seem to find a similar way to do this for Python (a solution I found was to use histogram, which makes me uncomfortable since we are taught to only use histograms for continuous data).

Is there a way around this? Mainly to tabulate factors that is in a long list/ array/ vector, and plot it out if possible via a bar chart.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean, could you give a complete example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Take a look at the pandas library..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

siblings_number = [1, 2 ,3, 2, 1, 0, 0]

table = pd.DataFrame(siblings_number)
table.plot.bar()
```

[image]